# How can I trace recursion in C programming?

Tags: c, recursion

I was trying to trace the recursion. In my logic answer should be 30, but the answer is 36. My question is how to trace this recursion?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(int n)
{
    int static x=0;
    if(n>=0)
    {
        x=x+1;
        return(fun(n-1)+x);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    printf("%d",fun(a));    
}
```

Comment: With a debugger (or add printouts)?

Comment: You can run your program line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) while monitoring the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and the values of all variables.

Comment: How would you trace a non-recursive program? In other words, what's your actual question? I feel like recursion isn't the real problem here.

Comment: Add one or more *printf* in *fun()*

Answer (score 4):

If you are not used to using a debugger, it's probably a good time to start using one.

Until then, you could add printouts to see what your program is doing:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int n) {
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    int static x = 0;
    if (n >= 0) {
        x = x + 1;        
        int res = fun(n - 1);
        printf("returning fun(%d)\t%d + %d = %d\n", n - 1, res, x, res + x);
        return res + x;
    }
    printf("termination point reached, x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    printf("%d\n", fun(a));
}
```

Output:

```
n=5
n=4
n=3
n=2
n=1
n=0
n=-1
termination point reached, x = 6
returning fun(-1)   0 + 6 = 6
returning fun(0)    6 + 6 = 12
returning fun(1)    12 + 6 = 18
returning fun(2)    18 + 6 = 24
returning fun(3)    24 + 6 = 30
returning fun(4)    30 + 6 = 36
36
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function has undefined behavior because evaluations of the operands in the addition expression in the return statement

```
return(fun(n-1)+x);
```

are unsequenced. That is the value of `x` in the first call of the function can be evaluated before the next recursive call of the function. In this case `x` will be equal to `1`. If the value of `x` will be evaluated after the next recursive call of the function it can have another value because the variable `x` has static storage duration.

From the C Standard (6.5 Expressions)

> 2 If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to
> either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
> computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
> undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
> unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

So in different compilers you can get different results depending on how the compilers generate the object code.